# Как задается кодировка в php?

Tags: кодировка, php

Как задается кодировка в php?

Comment: @ААА, уточните суть вопроса. Вы про файлы, про подключение mysql, про определение браузером кодировки на странице или про что-то еще?

Comment: Я имею ввиду чтобы в браузере код отображался правильно ,написанный в нотепд++,без каких-либо файлов

Answer (score 1):

для конвертации кодировки строк в php есть функция iconv().

Это еще не все, вам нужно еще в правильную кодировку сами файлы сменить, в notepad++, это делается так:

В меню есть вкладка "Кодировки", там можно преобразовать.

Еще и в meta-тегах html страницы должна нужная кодировка стоять.

Например:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html  charset=windows-1251" />

Comment: Все равно кодировка не работает,хотя преобразовал и utf-8 без bom,а с помощью файла все нормально получается,есть ли в них разница.задавать кодировку через нотепад или скидывать в папку файл